# IStream to MSXML DOMDocument

Tags: c++, msxml, istream

Is there a simple way for me to take an IStream of an XML document and then load it in to an IXMLDOMDocument (msxml)? Preferably without writing the stream to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) out! [More example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

An [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) based [`ISequentialStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implementation example: [link](https://github.com/naszta/VtkMsXml/blob/master/vtkSequentialStream.cxx). ([`ISequentialStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the base class of [`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
// VARIANT_TRUE != TRUE !!!!!!!!!!!
VARIANT_BOOL retval = VARIANT_TRUE;
// document object created by CoCreateInstance
IXMLDOMDocument* xml_doc;
// own ISequentialStream/IStream instance (like example)
ISequentialStream* streamaddress;
// variant: could be IStream, ISequentialStream or IPersistStream
VARIANT xmlSource;
// variant init
VariantInit(&xmlSource);
// your object is an IUnknown interface
xmlSource.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
// set its address
xmlSource.punkVal = streamaddress;
// load XML from stream
if ( ( xml_doc->load(xmlSource,&retval) == S_OK ) && ( retval == VARIANT_TRUE ) ) {
  // done
}
```

[`VARIANT_TRUE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`SHCreateMemStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream):

```cpp
bool load_xml_string(IXMLDOMDocument* xml_doc, std::string const& xml_string){
  CComPtr<IStream> stream;
  stream.Attach(SHCreateMemStream((const BYTE*)xml_string.c_str(),
                                  (UINT)xml_string.size()));
  VARIANT_BOOL load_result = VARIANT_FALSE;
  return (xml_doc->load(CComVariant(static_cast<IUnknown*>(&stream)), &load_result) == S_OK &&
          load_result == VARIANT_TRUE);
}
```